# Embed QtDesigner

Tags: qt, pyqt

Is it possible to embed QtDesigner into a PyQt application.  I did some searching but can't really find any examples. Found lots about using the interface API but not really how to get the interface in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make 3 steps:

1. Get QtDesigner & QtCreator source
2. Create bindings from QtDesigner C++ code to python using SIP or Shiboken
3. Look at QtCreator source of how to embed QtDesigner into your application

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to do it without the source code. I doubt Qt will hand it out either. https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator is the source for QtCreator, but I could not find anything similar for QtDesigner.